# References discussing the carbon footprint expected for fault-tolerant quantum computers?

Tags: resource-request, experimental-realization

There are many problems regarding the scalability of quantum computers, how we need good quantum error correcting codes that scale well and protect well the logical encodings against many possible sources of noise.

Are there references that have decided to analyse the carbon footprint linked to quantum computation?

Comment: I think I have found an answer to this question at this paper here https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/abstract/10.1103/PRXQuantum.3.020101; it seems that this is being discussed but it is not yet fully worked out.

Comment: One thing that may be interesting to compare, considering for instance results in sample complexity of quantum algorithms, is to compare the possible carbon footprint between the ones with a fully quantum processing usage with respect to those that are using only prepare-and-measure like things...